# How can pass data and communicate between two iOS applications in two device in local network?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a iOS application. I want to do something like:
I have a primary iPad(Pro),and a secondary iPad(air). First of all, I want to transfer data between two ipads. ex. iPad pro send a data "total = 100", then iPad air show on screen "I got total = 100" when it receive datas. 
Second of all, I want iPad pro to be able to control iPad air.ex. iPad pro says "open your camera", then iPad air open its camera.

Is there any framework to be able to achieve this goal? If there are some example code, it will be great!

**Edit:**
In this process, I should not touch anything iPad air. The data should automatically show up in iPad air

Comment: MultipeerConnectivity.framework?

Comment: @Larme by using this framework, do I need to do something on iPad air? for ex, do I need trigger any event on iPad air to receive data?

Comment: You have to use your own protocol. The second device can't understand by itself that "total = 100" means that it have to show "I got total = 100". And "Open your camera" means that it has to show its camera. You have to create your "language". Example: "show:messageToShow", "action:openCamera", "action:openSafari", etc.

Comment: Multipeer is good, but if you just need to connect two iPads locally, and send small amounts of data, go with core bluetooth! Posted some code to get you going...

Comment: Tutorial for Multipeer Connectivity on two devices: https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/

Answer (score 2):

Ok this is not multiplier, its vanilla bluetooth. But if you just want to play, then its good.

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

class BLEManager  {
var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
var bleHandler : BLEHandler // delegate
init() {
self.bleHandler = BLEHandler()
self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self.bleHandler, queue: nil)
} 
}

class BLEHandler : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
override init() {
super.init()
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
switch (central.state)
{
case .Unsupported:
print("BLE is unsupported")
case .Unauthorized:
print("BLE is unauthorized")
case .Unknown:
print("BLE is unknown")
case .Resetting:
print("BLE is reseting")
case .PoweredOff:
print("BLE is powered off")
case .PoweredOn:
print("BLE is powered on")
central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
default:
print("BLE default")
}
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral     peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
print("didConnectPeripheral")
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!,
didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!,
adverismentData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!,
RSSI: NSNumber!)
{
print("\(peripheral.name) : \(RSSI) dBm") 
}
}
```

You call it with ...

```
var bleManager = BLEManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
bleManager = BLEManager()
}
```

This is just the central; you need to implement the peripheral side :).

Comment: great !!! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

MultipeerConnectivity framework is a good start if you just need to exchange simple data in the form of messages
Apple provide a sample code: [MultipeerGroupChat](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013691)
An other solution is to use the GameCenter framework, but t's more complex to put in place and not recommended if you are not developing a game